# Way to store featured image width and height in two separate variables?

Tags: functions, theme-development, images

i have added a function like this to generate custom image size

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'slider_image');

    function slider_image(){
        add_image_size( 'slide_image', 540, 405);
    }
```

I want to store the width and height to **2 separate variables**, so that i can **compare it later** if the featured image is **less than the width or height**, i can hide such posts on the blog page!

Logic to do it will be a bonus for me!

Any help to do it in best way possible will be appreciated!

Comment: if you use this field to save any post detail than, you can save this field value as `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);`    for update `update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);`

Comment: Sorry, it won't work

Comment: of course, this code will not work directly. this is the concept to save data.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the [`wp_get_additional_image_sizes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_additional_image_sizes/) function to retrieve an image "size" (i.e. width, height, and the 'crop' option), like this:

```
$image_sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();
if ( isset( $image_sizes['slide_image'] ) ) {
    $size = $image_sizes['slide_image'];
    var_dump( $size ); // Demo
    echo $size['width']; // Demo
}
```

**UPDATE**

In reply to your comment,

> i want to get the current post featured image width and height..how to
>   do it

Use the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function:

> The returned array contains four values: the URL of the attachment
>   image src, *the width of the image file, the height of the image file*,
>   and a boolean representing whether the returned array describes an
>   intermediate (generated) image size or the original, full-sized
>   upload.

— More on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_additional_image_sizes/

But anyway, try this `function`:

```
// See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/301465/137402
function my_wpse301465( $image_size, $post = null ) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );

    $info = $post_thumbnail_id ?
        wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $image_size ) : null;

    if ( $info ) {
        $sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();
        $size = isset( $sizes[ $image_size ] ) ? $sizes[ $image_size ] : null;

        return $size ? (
            $info[1] < $size['width'] ||
            $info[2] < $size['height']
        ) : false;
    }
}
```

And here's how you could use it:

```
// Or pass a post ID as in my_wpse301465( 'slide_image', 123 ).
if ( my_wpse301465( 'slide_image' ) ) {
    echo 'Hide featured image.';
} else {
    echo 'Show featured image.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, i want to get the current post featured image width and height..how to do it? Please help me!

Comment: I've actually updated the answer. Check it out.